# Reshaping data of different time lengths in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I want to perform several repeated measures on my data. I first need to reshape the dataframe from a wide to a long format to do that.

This is my dataframe:

```
    ID Group x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z1  z2
    144 1   566 613 597 563 549 562 599  469
    167 2   697 638 756 682 695 693 718  439.5
    247 4   643 698 730 669 656 669 698  514.5
    317 4   633 646 641 520 543 586 559  405.5
    344 3   651 678 708 589 608 615 667  514
    352 2   578 702 671 536 594 579 591  467.5
    382 1   678 690 693 555 565 534 521  457.5
    447 3   668 672 718 663 689 751 784  506.5
    464 2   760 704 763 514 554 520 564  486
    628 1   762 789 783 618 610 645 625  536
```

As you might notice, I have measured variable x and y on three time points and variable z at two points. I was wondering if it makes sense at all to try and reshape the data into long format, given the fact that I have separate time lengths.

I have not been able to do so. So first of all, does it even make sense to do it this way? Or should I make two dataframes? Second, if it does make sense, how?

EDIT: I would expect something like:

```
ID Group Timex  Timey Timez  x    y    z
144 1     1       1     1   566  563  599
144 1     2       2     2   613  549  469
144 1     3       3         597  562
167 2     1       1     1   697  682  718
167 2     2       2     2   638  695  439.5 
167 2     3       3         756  693
....
```

But I'm not even sure if that makes sense at all, to have these empty cells?

Comment: Can u show the expected output?

Comment: i'm with akrun on this one. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I added my expectation. I did not include that first, because I am not even sure if this is possible or if it even makes sense!

Comment: @Inkling After I posted my answer, I just noticed that you asked a similar question before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850034/how-do-i-use-the-reshape-function-more-than-once-succesfully-in-r) and this questions has been marked as a duplicate. Is there any reason why you posted a similar question again, especially it is a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To me, these we two separate questions, my other question was on how to use the reshape function for multiple variables at once (which I did not notice before it was a duplicate, I could remove my question if that's common practice? ). My question here was specifically on the fact if the variables have different lengths. (I used a similar dataset as illustration, but notice I left out z3 in this example). After my first question got answered, I got stuck with this problem, so to me, this was a follow up.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Unless there are other concerns, I feel like you don't have to remove your last question. There were others giving nice answers to your question. If you remove that, all the associated answers will be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea. `dt_all` is the final output. Notice that this example does not create `Timex`, `Timey`, and `Timez`, but I would argue that one column called `Time` is sufficient and individual `Timex`, `Timey`, and `Timez` are redundant.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Process the data
dt_all <- dt %>%
  gather(Var, Value, -ID, -Group) %>%
  mutate(Time = sub("[a-z]", "", Var), Type = sub("[0-9]", "", Var)) %>%
  select(-Var) %>%
  spread(Type, Value)
```

#### Data Preparation

```
# Create example data frames
dt <- read.table(text = "ID Group x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z1  z2
    144 1   566 613 597 563 549 562 599  469
                 167 2   697 638 756 682 695 693 718  439.5
                 247 4   643 698 730 669 656 669 698  514.5
                 317 4   633 646 641 520 543 586 559  405.5
                 344 3   651 678 708 589 608 615 667  514
                 352 2   578 702 671 536 594 579 591  467.5
                 382 1   678 690 693 555 565 534 521  457.5
                 447 3   668 672 718 663 689 751 784  506.5
                 464 2   760 704 763 514 554 520 564  486
                 628 1   762 789 783 618 610 645 625  536",
                 header = TRUE)
```